# Location of Relocation table in ELF file

Tags: elf, relocation, readelf

I don't find any information about where is located the relocation table in ELF file.

My project is to display information about a ELF file like `readelf`. I did the display of the Header, Section Header and Symbol table but I don't know where to find the relocation table.

**Could anyone explain me where relocation table is in ELF file ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of ELF file you are talking about, and in any case there
can be more than one relocation table.

In an ELF 32-bit object file, static code relocations are specified in the `rel.text` section;
for an ELF 64-bit object file, static code relocations are specified in the `rela.text` section.
There may be additional static relocation sections `{rel|rela}.???` that specify relocations for objects in the `???` section, e.g. `.rela.eh_frame`, `.rela.init_array`.

In an ELF executable or DSO, the `.rela.dyn` section specifies dynamic relocations for variables.
The `rela.plt` section specifies dynamic relocations for functions.